# Progress Bar refreshing issue in an ajax

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, progress-bar

Iam a newbie to MVC and have a problem with updating progress bar.
I have a long running updation code inside my controller and i had to show a progress bar to indicate the status.So I broke down the updation codes into 5 parts and did the same from 5 individual ajax request.In between each ajax request I wrote the code for updating the progress bar.Once I run the application the progress update is not displayed after each request and its only being displayed at the end. If an alert is placed between each request the progress can be seen accordingly.
Is there anything I can do for refreshing the UI

Comment: Can you show some of your code please?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply...the issue was because I was not handling the ajax calls properly...Now I have changed the implementation and has switched to signalR to avoid the round trip..will post the codes once I have completed it...